# Accuracy between my IDE and PythonTutor.com?

Tags: python, algorithm, precision

I've been working on a problem for my online Python course and have noticed something weird in my solution for a fast way to calculate the least common multiple of two numbers: when I submit my code, it is marked incorrect and the correct answer is given next to my code's output, as below:

```
def lcm_fast(a, b):
    x, y = min([a, b]), max([a, b])
    def gcd_naive(a, b):
        if b == 0:
            return a
        else:
            return gcd_naive(b, a%b)
    return int(x * y / gcd_naive(x, y))
```

When submitted, returns:

Your output:
46374212988031352

Correct output:
46374212988031350

I felt that since these two answers are so remarkably close -- given they are the result of multiplying the two input numbers and dividing by 5 (their Greatest Common Denominator (gcd)), -- the issue may be in rounding of floating points or something similar, because I've noticed that commonly floats are actually something like 4.0000000000003 instead of an even 4.0.

When this exact code is run in PythonTutor.com, the correct answer is returned, 46374212988031350.

I've searched for this on Google and saw that in Python 2, numbers can actually be too long and therefore need to be indicated as long ints, but this was removed in Python 3 (which I, PythonTutor, and the submission site all use).

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: What a and b do you use?

Comment: print(lcm_fast(226553150,1023473145))
My question was marked as a duplicate though and the linked question solved it by suggesting integer devision (retrospective *duh* to myself)